# Segmentation fault as soon as i run my code. Seems like problem with arrays

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote code which prompts the user for a number, then tell which digits are of that number are repeated.
While there is no problem with compilation, it shows segmentation fault(core dumped) when i run it.

Code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
    int n=0;
    int digit[n];
    int t;
    
    for (int num = 0;num<10;num++)
    {
        digit[num] = 0;
    }
    
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int y=t;
    int c = 0;
    
    do
    {
        c++;
        y = y/10;
    }while(y>0);
    
    int ko;
    
    for (int no=0;no<c;no++)
    {
        ko = t%10;
        digit[ko]++;
        t=t/10;
    }
    
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int co = 0;co<10;co++)
    {
        if (count>0)
            printf(" ");
    
        if (digit[co]>1)
        {
            printf("%d",co);
            count ++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `int n=0; int digit[n];` That creates an array that can store 0 elements. Need at least `int digit[10];`

Comment: `int n=0;
 int digit[n];` but why?

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies here:

```
int n=0;
int digit[n];
```

This makes `digit` an array of 0 `int`s, which is not what you need.
Looking at

```
for (int num = 0;num<10;num++)
{
    digit[num] = 0;
}
```

This makes me think that you need to iterate over 10 array elements.
So make it,

```
int digit[10];
```

Or even better define a macro and use it elsewhere.

```
#define LIMIT_ARRAY_ELEMENTS (10)
```

and then

```
int digit[LIMIT_ARRAY_ELEMENTS];
```

and

```
for (int num = 0; num < LIMIT_ARRAY_ELEMENTS; num++)
```

The segmentation fault you see is because you have not allocated enough memory for what you are trying to do.